# Building around data studio

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to build an email login & customizable user subscriptions around data studio?

We have a basic dashboard with individual metrics for locations and would like to have different access for different levels of paid users

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your Data Studio reports into your own website, so yeah. You'd have to manage the login/subscriptions yourself though. Quickest way would be a CMS like WordPress.

Or you could manually share the Data Studio report with individual emails using the share button (top right of a report).

For different levels of access it sounds like you need a report for each level.

*Still learning Data Studio so this is just my opinion :)*